# LINQ, output arguments, and 'Use of Unassigned Local Variable' error

Tags: c#, linq, tryparse

I have some code similar to the following.

```
class MyClass<TEnum> where TEnum : struct
{
    public IEnumerable<TEnum> Roles { get; protected set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> roles = ... ;

        TEnum value;
        Roles = from r in roles
                where Enum.TryParse(r, out value)
                select value;   // <---- ERROR HERE!
    }
}
```

However, on the line indicated above, I get the error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'value'

Seems to me that `value` will always be initialized in this case since it is an `out` parameter to `Enum.TryParse`.

Is this a bug with the C# compiler?

Comment: Similar to [linq with unassigned variable parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4082288/95573)

Comment: @SwDevMan81: That's not at all the same.

Comment: btw.: Even if it would compile and do its thing --- your code would still be buggy. As you select an outside variable, that is closed over, the value is the same for all members of your resulting list. You might as well `select 0`. The most elegant solution would be a TryParse extension method that returns int?

Comment: @JonathanWood: It's got a lot in common, actually.  The fact that the "definitely assigned" status is checked when the lambda is constructed, not when it is called, is the root cause of both.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster: You mean `Parse`?  But that throws an exception on failure.  He wants zero items from each parsing failure and one item from each successful parse... which could be accomplished using `SelectMany`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The underlying issue may be the same, but the code is different. Someone who does not know the underlying cause is unlikely to see the two items as directly related without first doing a lot of reading.

Comment: One can also write a short helper method that returns a Nullable<TEnum> and tries to parse it internally. Then, do something like: `from r in roles
let tmp = helpermethod(r)
                where tmp != null
                select tmp; `

Comment: [More discussion on this topic](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/544755)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Error says the variable is (provably) unassigned -- FALSE.  Reality, variable is not provably assigned (using the proof theorems available to the compiler).

---

LINQ is designed with the assumption of *pure* functions... those that return outputs based on the input and have no side effects.

Once this is rewritten, it will be:

```
roles.Where(r => Enum.TryParse(r, out value)).Select(r => value);
```

and rewritten again to

```
Enumerable.Select(Enumerable.Where(roles, r => Enum.TryParse(r, out value)), r => value);
```

These LINQ functions will call the filter lambda before any calls to the selection lambda, but the compiler can't know that (at least, not without either special-casing or cross-module dataflow analysis).  More problematically, if a different implementation of `Where` were chosen by overload resolution, then possibly the lambda with `TryParse` would NOT be called.

The compiler's rules for definite assignment are very simplistic, and err on the side of safety.

Here is another example:

```
bool flag = Blah();
int value;
if (flag) value = 5;
return flag? value: -1;
```

It is impossible for an uninitialized value to be used, yet the language rules for dataflow analysis lead to a compile error that `value` is used without being "definitely assigned".

The compiler error is worded poorly, however.  Not being "definitely assigned" is not the same as definitely being "unassigned", as the error purports.

Answer (score 6):

No it is not.

Compiler cannot guarantee that `Enum.TryParse(r, out value)` will be executed.

What if `roles` is an empty collection?

Even if you initialize your collection in the method CSC does not consider `roles` to have values - it is a thing that compiler currently cannot do.

What if lambda with `Enum.TryParse(r, out value)` will not be executed - `value` won't get its value through the closure?

Compiler cannot give you such guarantees.

---

Your code is (partially) equivalent to:

```
class MyClass<TEnum> where TEnum : struct
{
    public IEnumerable<TEnum> Roles { get; protected set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> roles = ... ;


        Roles = GetValues();   // <---- ERROR HERE!
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetValues(IEnumerable<String> roles)
    {       
        TEnum value; 
        String[] roleArray = roles.ToArray(); // To avoid the foreach loop.

        // What if roleArray.Length == 0?
        for(int i = 0; i < roleArray.Length; i++)
        {
             // We will never get here
             if (Enum.TryParse(roleArray[i], out value))
                 yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

And this code is clean and understandable for the compiler(no errors) - it knows that without the execution of the `Enum.TryParse(roleArray[i], out value)` you won't try to return `value`.

---

But it is not so simple with functional LINQ query.

If we rewrite it with Enumerable extensions we will have:

```
 TEnum value;
 Roles =  roles
     .Where(role => Enum.TryParse(role, out value))
     .Select(role => value);   <---- STILL ERROR HERE!
```

And we again get the error.

Compiler cannot see that `value` will be unquestionably set, because it does not understand the innards of the methods used - `Where` may or (theoretically)may not execute the lambda, so if you add the fact that `value` variable is used in closure, it becomes a non trivial task to make such guarantees without false positives.

Comment: Then `value` will not be evaluated either.

Comment: Yeah, what @BenVoigt said. Although I do realize that is getting to be a complex variation for the compiler to detect, it still seems wrong.

Comment: "What if roles is an empty collection?" , that is +1.

Comment: "It is an optimization that compiler current cannot do" - So, in other words, a bug since the error is technically incorrect.

Comment: @Habib: Please read the other comments to see what is being said about this.

Comment: @JonathanWood: No, it's a shortcoming in the language specification.  The compiler has no bug since it implements the specification.

Comment: @BenVoigt: So it's a bug in the spec? :)

Comment: @JonathanWood - It's not a bug since the compiler doesn't know that `Where` will call `TryParse` at all. `Where` is just an extension method and isn't special.

Comment: @Lee: But the error message makes an assertion that is untrue.

Comment: No, the code is NOT equivalent!  In particular, your version is perfectly OK!

Comment: @JonathanWood - It's not untrue - `Enum.TryParse` is not guaranteed to be called so `values` is not definitely assigned.

Comment: @JonathanWood, consider `int value;var query = new string[] { }.Select(r => int.TryParse(r, out value));Console.WriteLine(value);` This will still give the error for `value` being unassigned. Since `TryParse` will not be called, as the collection is empty.

Comment: @Habib: So?  That's a very different case.

Comment: @JonathanWood: It's a shortcoming.  Not a bug.  So is the fact that the compiler doesn't warn about all cases of infinite loops.  But that's not a bug either.  In fact, a specification that required the opposite *would* be incorrect, since it would require the compiler to solve the Halting Problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt, `int value; var query = new string[] { "1", "2" }.Where(r => int.TryParse(r, out value)).Select(r => value);` looks similar ? Compiler has to follow the [Definite assignment rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and *compiler* can't determine whether `value` will be assigned or not.

Comment: @Habib: Correct.  Because it can't determine whether value is assigned or unassigned, it's poor wording to say the variable is, for sure, unassigned.

Comment: Poor wording, *may be*, But there is no way for compiler to determine with `static flow analysis` that value will definitely be assigned.

Comment: @Lee: The error is that an unassigned value was used when in fact it is never used if it is not assigned. Therefore, the assertion by the error message is technically not correct, regardless of the reasons why.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, it is a shortcoming. My background was in C and C++, which will let you assign uninitialized data all day long. Now, I understand the reasons for the compiler to prevent this, but still it always felt a little restrictive to me, especially in cases like this where my code really is quite valid.